# body and head tags are disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, head

First off I am not a web developer and have little experience in coding. I am trying to validate my website on Google Search Console. The web developer isn't returning my calls and the CMS I am using is an old layout style system.

I can't verify my site when trying all of the console's method, since the coding already in place isn't accepting `<head>` and `<body>` tags. Every time I add an HTML tag, Google Analytics tag, Google Tag manager snippet, the system overrides any new additional tags I add resulting in not being able to verify my website.

Apparently, my website mira-center.com is not indexed by Google (I suspect by the developer) as it's not appearing in the search results when I type the company's name Mira Training Center.

Comment: First verify as told here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en . You will need to add a file to your server folder and some other things. This will add it to google.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I don't have the server credentials.